# Split Consecutive string data into desired vertical output

Tags: java, html, css, regex, jsp

I am displaying output in jsp page using scriplets.

I am getting output from database as follows:

```
  out.println(a) ; //prints output Jan-2019 Feb-2019 March-2019 April-2019

  out.println(b) ; //prints output 100100200300
```

I am trying to print the output in jsp page using html css as follows:

```
    Month           Price
    Jan-2019         100
    Feb-2019         100
    March-2019       200
    April-2019       300
```

I searched a lot in google still didn't find any solution also tried with different regex code still its not resolved. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: The ```b``` variable doesn't have any delimiter, thus how can you determine where to split the input? Also please include how did you get the values for variables ```a``` and ```b```

Comment: How can we know what numbers exactly in a String "100100200300"? It must be some delimiter

Comment: @Mark I got the variable b from database. in database data is stored like 100200300400. We can split the data ending at zero and before beginning at any number right ?

Comment: @Tom no you can't do that, since price might be 101,201,301, thus DB data will look like 101201301. Your logic in splitting will fail

Comment: @Mark no no price is 100200300400 like this only. There is no 101201

Comment: @Tom then if that's the case then you can proceed with your splitting logic, what's the problem then?

Comment: kindly post the solution i will be grateful

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code.  It was intentionally made more "verbose" so as to facilitate more use of Regular Expressions with your data feed.

```
String a = "Jan-2019 Feb-2019 March-2019 April-2019";
String b = "100100200300";

Pattern P1 = Pattern.compile("(\\w{3,})-(\\d{4})");
Pattern P2 = Pattern.compile("[1-9]+0+");

Vector<Integer> years = new Vector<>();
Vector<String> months = new Vector<>();
Vector<Integer> prices = new Vector<>();

Matcher m = P1.matcher(a);
while (m.find())
{
    months.add(m.group(1));
    years.add(new Integer(m.group(2)));
}

m = P2.matcher(b);
while (m.find()) prices.add(new Integer(m.group()));

// Useful for debugging, to make sure these are "parallel arrays"
// Parallel Arrays are almost *always* useful when regular-expressions & parsing is "happening."
System.out.println( "years.size():\t" + years.size() + '\n' +
                    "months.size():\t" + months.size() + '\n' +
                    "prices.size():\t" + prices.size() + "\n\n"   );

int len = years.size();
for (int i=0; i < len; i++)
    System.out.println( months.elementAt(i) + " " +
                        years.elementAt(i) + ":\t" +
                        prices.elementAt(i) );

System.exit(0);
```

Here is the output:

> ```
> years.size():   4
> months.size():  4
> prices.size():  4
>
>
> Jan 2019:       100
> Feb 2019:       100
> March 2019:     200
> April 2019:     300
> ```

Answer (score 1):

For splitting `a` do this:

```
String[] months = a.split(" ");
```

For splitting `b` do this:

```
ArrayList<String> prices = new ArrayList<String>();
boolean isZero = false;
String tmpPrice = "";
for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
    if (i + 1 >= b.length()) {
        tmpPrice = tmpPrice + b.charAt(i);
        prices.add(tmpPrice);
    } else if (isZero && b.charAt(i) != '0') {
        prices.add(tmpPrice);
        tmpPrice = "" + b.charAt(i);
        isZero = false;
    } else if (b.charAt(i) == '0') {
        isZero = true;
        tmpPrice = tmpPrice + b.charAt(i);
    } else if (b.charAt(i) != '0') {
        isZero = false;
        tmpPrice = tmpPrice + b.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: it shows output like this : 1 10 100 1 10 100 1 10 100 1 10 100 ,actually output should display vertically css as I have mentioned in question. I added <table> <tr><td><%out.println(tmpPrice);%></td></tr></table> But its not showing output as above mentioned in question

Comment: @Tom the separator for ```b``` works well for me for the input ```110100110100110100110100```. Maybe it is how you coded the HTML part. Kindly add how you coded it in your question and I'll try to help

Comment: where should i put out.println(tmpPrice); ??

Comment: @Tom kindly edit your question and add how you printed the price and the date. Add the HTML part of your code